# com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_get_time(Native method) crash

Tags: android, ssl

There have been a lot of crashes in the past two days. It seems to be a problem with the network requesting SSL certification, but I don’t know what the root cause is.

See the crash log below

```
#00 pc 000000000003b6f0 /apex/com.android.conscrypt/lib64/libssl.so (SSL_SESSION_get_time+4)
#01 pc 00000000000336b0 /apex/com.android.conscrypt/lib64/libjavacrypto.so (_ZL25NativeCrypto_SSL_get_timeP7_JNIEnvP7_jclasslP8_jobject+124)
#02 pc 0000000000151350 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+144)
#03 pc 00000000001485b8 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568)
#04 pc 00000000001571d4 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+284)
#05 pc 00000000002fe588 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter34ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_11ShadowFrameEtPNS_6JValueE+384)
#06 pc 00000000002f9858 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+912)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_get_time(Native method)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.getTime(NativeSsl.java:101)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ActiveSession.isValid(ActiveSession.java:148)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ActiveSession.getSessionContext(ActiveSession.java:67)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.SessionSnapshot.<init>(SessionSnapshot.java:46)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.transitionTo(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:1168)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.close(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:970)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.Util.closeQuietly(Util.java:91)
at com.android.okhttp.ConnectionPool.cleanup(ConnectionPool.java:288)
at com.android.okhttp.ConnectionPool$1.run(ConnectionPool.java:99)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
```